# I want to include different page types

Tags: php

I have something like this:

```
<?php   $pages = array('home', 'docs', 'app', 'userg','appviz');
            if (!isset($_GET['_page']) || !in_array($_GET['_page'], $pages))
                list($_page) = $pages;
            else
                $_page = $_GET['_page'];

            include "pages/{$_page}.html";
        ?>
```

I want to include `"pages/{$_page}.php"` along with the .html.
How do i do that?

Comment: What if both a `.html` and `.php` file exists with the same name?

Comment: Not really an answer but you must sanitize your `$_GET['_page']` value before using it.

Comment: That's not the problem here.

Comment: @haim770 path traversal attack

Comment: I can't understand what you want at all. Could you define `different page types` and could you provide a real example please.

Comment: @enenen I want to include .html , .php, or even without an extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [PHP manual for include()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML
> mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the
> end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be
> executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid PHP start and end
> tags.

Since `include()` is expecting a PHP file you should check out [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).
*Note: the behavior changed after PHP 5.*

```
$target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pages/$_page.html";
$html_file = file_get_contents($target_file, true);
echo $html_file;
```

If you're trying to get PHP to parse an HTML document like a PHP file, then you'll need to add the directive to your server config or your server `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Then you could use `include()`, `include_once()`, `require()`, and `require_once()`.